# Save IndexedRowMatrix to file in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've a matrix of type IndexRowMatrix.

```
Array(IndexedRow(0,(3,[0,2],[1.0,1.0])), IndexedRow(1,(3,[0,1],[1.0,1.0])), IndexedRow(2,(3,[0],[1.0])))
```

I tried writing it to csv file

```
indexedRowMatrix.rows.saveAsFile("/user/test/output.csv")
```

The output is in the format of

```
 IndexedRow(0,(3,[0,2],[1.0,1.0])), IndexedRow(1,(3,[0,1],[1.0,1.0])), IndexedRow(2,(3,[0],[1.0]))
```

I want to be in the following format

```
1.0  ,    0   ,   1.0
1.0  ,   1.0  ,    0
1.0  ,    0   ,    0
```

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the `map` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution

```
val test = indexedRowMatrix.rows.map( x=> x.vector.toDense)
test.coalesce(1, true).saveAsTextFile("rdd")
```